# Go json.NewDecoder vs. json.Unmarshal Memory

Tags: json, go, decode

I'm currently learning Go and have built a small API in which I search for and summarize data from several other APIs.

Now I noticed that if I use the following to access the data of multiple requests

```golang
json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&example)
```

the memory usage of the API spikes up to about 250mb

but if I use

```golang
byteBody, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
err = json.Unmarshal(byteBody, &example)
```

instead the memory usage is like 150mb less.

does anyone have an explanation for this? Sorry if this is a dump question but im still learning :D

Comment: Generally using a decoder (`json.NewDecoder()`) should be more efficient in terms of memory usage as that doesn't require reading and holding all JSON data in memory at once. However, this doesn't apply to all JSON inputs, there may be inputs that give opposite results as in your case. We don't see your inputs, so we can't give more insights. If this matters to you, use whichever is more efficient to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So there is no correct or wrong way when using one of this two approaches?

Comment: There is no solution that's best in all scenarios. You can optimize to certain inputs from certain aspects. Generally `json.NewDecoder()` uses less memory. If your input JSON is so large that it doesn't fit into memory, then `json.Unmarshal()` is obviously out of the question, while `json.Decoder` may easily process that.

Comment: 1. "memory usage of the API spikes up to about 250mb" All this "memory usage" is _complicated_. Unless you exactly define _what_ kind of memory usage you are talking about knowbody can help you. 2. 250mb is nothing, absoluteliy nothing, just forget about it. 3. Chances your experiment actually measures what you think are low.